# Find the probability that $P( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq (\frac{X^2}{Y^2})\leq\sqrt{2})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

**PROBLEM:** Given that $X$, $Y$ are indepedent uniformly distributed r.vs's over range $[0,1]$ with their joint pdf given by: $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$ 
 
find $P( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq (\frac{X^2}{Y^2})\leq\sqrt{2})=?$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Solving the inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq (\frac{X^2}{Y^2})\leq\sqrt{2}$ 
 gives us the following result: $(2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot x \leq y\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot x).$ 
 
Hence, $P( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq (\frac{X^2}{Y^2})\leq\sqrt{2})=P(2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot x \leq y\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot x)=P(y\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot x)-P(2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot x \leq y)$

From here I don't know how to proceed further. I know joint pdf will be used  but I dont know how. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Correction: $$P( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq (\frac{X^2}{Y^2})\leq\sqrt{2})$$ $$=P(2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y \leq x\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y)$$ $$=P(x\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y)-P(x<2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y ).$$

Now $P(x\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y)=\int_0^{2^{-1/4}}\int_0^{2^{1/4}y} dx dy +\int_{2^{-1/4}} ^{1} \int_0^{1} dxdy$ and $P(x<2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y )=\int_0^{1} \int_0^{2^{-1/4}y} dx dy$.

For the first probability I have split the integral into two parts because $2^{1/4}y$ may exceed $1$ (in which case you have to integrate w.r.t $x$ from $0$ to $1$.

I will let you compute the integrals.

Comment: can you explain how did you split both expressions into integrals you have shown? Which formula, definiton you have used?

Comment: It helps to draw a picture. You are integrating over triangular regions in the plane.

Comment: There has to be specific math formula for evaluating such probability expressions like $P(X_1\leq Y \leq X_2)$ without need to rely on region

Comment: You have to integrate $f(x,y)$ over $\{(x,y): [0,1]\times [0,1]: x \leq 2^{1/4 y}\}$ for the first one.

Comment: I am not getting you. Can you please elaborate in detail how did you obtained above integrals you have obtained?

Comment: Isn't $$P(2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y \leq x\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y) = P(x\leq 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y)-P(x<2^{-\frac{1}{4}} \cdot y) \, ?$$

Comment: @Diger Yes, thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the answer.